# Folland complex measures total variation definition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, total-variation

Consider the following fragments from Folland's text on real analysis:

[image]

Why can proposition 3.9 be applied to show uniqueness? I.e. why is $\rho = \mu_1 + \mu_2$ $\sigma$-finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You spotted a "typo" in Folland (there are others).

In the definition of total variation of a complex measure $\nu$, Folland is assuming that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure (although he only says "$\mu$ is a positive measure"), that is why he can use Proposition 3.9 to prove the uniqueness.

**Remark:** You can also consider that the definition of total variation of a complex measure $\nu$ in Folland's is meant to be exacyly as written ($\mu$ being any positive measure,**not necessarily $\sigma$-finite**) and, to apply proposition 3.9, Folland **used without mentioning** the following result:

> Given $\nu$ be a complex measure,  $\mu$ be any positive measure (**not necessarily $\sigma$-finite**) and $f$ a measurable function such that
> $$\nu = \int f d\mu$$ (which means $\forall E \in \mathcal{M}: \nu(E) = \int_E f d \mu $). Then there is a $\sigma$-finite  positive measure $\mu_f$ such that
> $$\nu = \int f d\mu = \int f d\mu_f $$ and
> $$|\nu| = \int |f| d\mu_f = \int |f| d\mu$$

**Proof**: Since $\nu$ is a complex measure, its a finite measure. Since $\forall E \in \mathcal{M}: \nu(E) = \int_E f d \mu $, it follows that $f \in L^1(\mu)$. So we have that $[f\neq 0]= \{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite. Let us define $\mu_f$ by, $\forall E \in \mathcal{M}$,
$$ \mu_f(E) = \mu([f\neq 0]\cap E)$$
It is immediate that $\mu_f$ is a $\sigma$-finite  positive measure and
$$\nu = \int f d\mu = \int f \chi_{[f\neq 0]} d\mu =\int f d\mu_f $$ and
$$|\nu| = \int |f| d\mu_f = \int |f| \chi_{[f\neq 0]} d\mu= \int |f| d\mu$$.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that if $d \nu = f d \mu$ then $d |\nu| = |f|d \mu$ only holds when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite? Or can we still prove that this always holds, also if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: It holds even if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. But, for the definition of total variation of a complex measure, in the way that Folland does, we need to use only $\mu$ that are  $\sigma$-finite positive measure.

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe know if this is hard to prove? Because otherwise using an other definition would be better.

Comment: Welcome.  It would not be harder, just longer.

Comment: Any idea how to get started on that?

Comment: Let $\nu$ be a signed measure. Define the positive measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ (Jordan decomposition). Then $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$. And then define $|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^-$. 
We can prove that if $\mu$ is a positive measure and $\nu = \int f d\mu$ for some measurable function, then $\nu^+ = \int f^+ d\mu$ and  $\nu^- = \int f^- d\mu$ and $|\nu| = \int |f| d\mu$. 

Given $\nu$ be a complex measure, we have that $\Re(\nu)$ and $\Im(\nu)$ are finite signed measures. Apply to each one the previous results.

Comment: Thanks this was most helpful.

Comment: I could not quite work out your hint in your last comment. I managed to prove that $\nu^* = \int f^* d \mu$ and similarly for $\nu^-$ but could not proceed then. See here for the follow up : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811807/show-that-if-nue-int-e-f-d-mu-then-nue-int-e-f-d-mu Thanks.